# Prove that $\emptyset$ is always an element of an algebra $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: measure-theory

We define an algebra $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(M)$ as follows

> 1. $\text{Not empty}$
> 2. $\forall X\subseteq M:X\in\mathcal{B}\implies M\setminus X\in\mathcal{B}$
> 3. $\forall X,Y\subseteq M:X\in \mathcal{B}\wedge Y\in \mathcal{B}\implies X\cup Y\in \mathcal{B}$

Where $\mathcal{P}$ is the powerset.

Using this, how can you prove that any $\mathcal{B}$ has to contain $\emptyset$ and $M$ itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axioms that define an algebra $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal P(M)$ are

> 1. $\mathcal B$ is non empty.
> 2. $\forall X\subseteq M:X\in\mathcal{B}\implies M\setminus X\in\mathcal{B}$.
> 3. $\forall X,Y\subseteq M:X\in \mathcal{B}\wedge Y\in \mathcal{B}\implies X\cup Y\in \mathcal{B}$.

Let some $X\in\mathcal B$ (due to the first axiom such $X$ exists) then we have that

- $M\setminus X\in\mathcal B$ due to the second axiom
- $X\cup (M\setminus X)=M\in\mathcal B$ due to the third axiom
- Then $M\setminus M=\emptyset\in\mathcal B$ due to the second axiom

Comment: This is the correct answer. If OP doesn't understand why it is correct, it might help in explaining to cite at each point where you use each of the axioms. "(because it is non-empty)" is the first axiom using OP's numbering, the first line is true because of the second axiom using OP's numbering, the second line is true because of the third axiom using OP's numbering, and the third line is true again using the second axiom of OP's numbering.